# Profiles - Pre Field and Post Field Help

Tags: civievent, profile, custom-fields

I'm working in with civi 4.6.4 in Wordpress, I used to be a Joomla user with a out of date civi and of course there are some changes to how profile fields render.

Previously all the content, pre field help, profile fields and post field help were in one div. Now they are broken into three separate divs, which is totally fine, I can see the advantages!! But the pre-field help and post field help have the same class and id, which is less than helpful. I can not target them separately (i.e. with css or javascript). Would it be too much to ask these be given separate ids in the future? Or has anyone come up with a way to target them separately without having to add code in with the whatever instructions you type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pre- and post- field help areas will have identifying CSS classes from CiviCRM 4.7.

This was the issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16328

And here's the patch / PR if you want to apply it to your current version of CiviCRM: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5667

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed!